# TTFB too high on one computer, not on another

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a web app for hotel that monitors guest checkin running in PHP/MySQL.

The checkin interface is composed of ajax calls that return data for a checkin to complete. The server where the web app is installed has a TTFB of 3.58 seconds.

What I did is I copied the web files and the whole database for comparison.
I installed xampp on my computer. Tried to run the same process, I got 100ms.

There are not much differences except that their server is faster than my home computer. All files and database is the same. What could be the culprit?

Here's my screenshot of Chrome's debugger tools (Home computer)
[image: Here's my screenshot of Chrome's debugger tools]

And here's their server
[image]

I hope I provided all the information you guys need to troubleshoot the issue.
I appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: This is a very, very broad question, as there are so many factors that could be contributing to this. What's the load like on the server? Are you using any caching on the server? How many processes are forked concurrently? Is this a Dedicated Server? VPS? Shared Hosting Environment? Is there are DNS resolution issue? Is there an issue with the backbone coming from the data center? Weather centric concerns perhaps?

Comment: Hi. This is just a simple implementation of a client-server model. It's not a server hosted on the web or anything. It's actually a local server that hosts the database and web application for different clients in a building. No caching or DNS issues.

Comment: When I search on `troubleshoot ttfb time` there are quite a few hits that look relevant - have you tried some of these? As @Ohgodwhy says, there are so many possible factors.